# Dropping Oracle Diskgroups with Oracle not running

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to startup an Oracle database in SQL*Plus, and I have the following error:

```
ORA-39510: CRS error performing start on instance 'MYDB' on 'MYDB'
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.DATA.dg' on 'my-db'
CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.DATA.dg start" encountered the following error:
ORA-15032: not all alterations performed
ORA-15017: diskgroup "DATA" cannot be mounted
ORA-15040: diskgroup is incomplete
ORA-15080: synchronous I/O operation failed to read block 0 of disk 1 in disk group
ORA-15080: synchronous I/O operation failed to read block 0 of disk 0 in disk group
ORA-15186: ASMLIB error function = [kfk_asm_ioerror],  error = [18446744073709551597],  mesg = [No such device]
ORA-15186: ASMLIB error function = [kfk_asm_ioerror],  error = [18446744073709551597],  mesg = [No such dev. For details refer to "(:CLSN00107:)" in "/u01/app/grid/diag/crs/my-db/crs/trace/ohasd_oraagent_grid.trc".
CRS-2674: Start of 'ora.DATA.dg' on 'my-db' failed
CRS-2679: Attempting to clean 'ora.DATA.dg' on 'my-db'
CRS-2681: Clean of 'ora.DATA.dg' on 'my-db' succeeded
CRS-0215: Could not start resource 'ora.mydb.db'.
clsr_start_resource:260 status:215
clsrapi_start_db:start_asmdbs status:215
```

Indeed, I do not have disks that were in DATA disk group, removed them physically.
Any attempts in dropping diskgroup DATA via ASMCMD were also failure.
Is there any way to drop this diskgroup manually (Without SQL*Plus and ASMCMD (they are NOT working!!!))?

Comment: **diskgroup "DATA" cannot be mounted`** seems pretty clear is this mounted?

Comment: @nbk nope, it is not mounted and it cannot be mounted. I do not have disks from this disk group

Comment: You may need to use `crsctl` to update the ASM and database dependencies in the cluster registry. You may still need `sqlplus` or `asmcmd` as that's the only way to modify the database and ASM internal configuration. As you've learned, you must always drop anything *in* such a disk group (tablespaces, data files, etc.), remove dependencies in the cluster registry, and de-confgure the disk group in ASM *before* removing the disks, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify diskgroup dependency of `mydb` (let's say you have a diskgroup called MYDBDG instead of DATA):

```
srvctl modify database -db my-db -diskgroup MYDBDG
```

Or remove the diskgroup dependency:

```
srvctl modify database -db my-db -nodiskgroup
```

Remove diskgroup resource from cluster:

```
srvctl remove diskgroup -g data
```

Start the database:

```
srvctl start database -db my-db
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked, no more diskgroup